# ODBC connection to RData

Tags: r, ms-access, odbc, rdata

We have some R programmers who are doing good scripting work. And we have some R muggles who would like to be able to look at the data. Is it possible to make an ODBC connection to an .RData file? And, from there, to use MS Access as a front end for running queries?

Answer (score 1):

No but you could probably put the data in postgresql and then access it from R and from your ODBC connection

Answer (score 0):

You can view the data in excel by creating a web server in R and use the from web option in excel

Not sure if the xls odbc driver will hen be able to server the info furthor